# Fundamental differences between $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and $e^{-x}$,

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

One of my students has asked for the differences between $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and $e^{-x}$, and I explained to her the differences in their domains, the continuity and differentiability of each function -- but also, I explained the similarities of both functions, particularly that they both have no roots and they are one-to-one functions, which means that they have inverse functions (for the purposes of Calculus I).

Is there something more fundamental and interesting that I can explain to her?  I feel I started to go off-topic in my email to her, when describing one-to-one functions, when instead she may be looking for a more basic answer about the two similar-looking exponentials.

Thanks,

Comment: the nth derivative is funny and different it gets more complicated with $e^{1/x}$ while with the second its simply $(-1)^ne^{-x}$

Comment: To give her the right answer you need to know why she want to know it. Maybe the reason for the question is the equality $\frac{1}{x}=x^{-1}$: if in the middle of some calculation we incorrectly replace $-x$ by $x^{-1}$ (due to inattention) the we get the wrong equality $e^{-x}=e^{1/x}$.

Comment: if $f(x)=1/x$ and $g(x)=e^x$ then your two functions are $f( g(x) ) $ and $g (f(x) )$

Comment: How are they similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fundamental difference is the asymptotic behavior: $e^{1/x}\overset{x\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1$ while $e^{-x}\overset{x\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$.

Another one: $e^{-x}$ have an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) indefinite integral while  $e^{1/x}$ does not.

Answer (score 3):

This is like explaining the differences and similarities between $f,g:\mathbb R_{> 0} \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=e^x$ by saying they are both one-to-one, have the same domain, and have no roots.

The two mentioned functions are very different, even when one restricts attention to the natural numbers. Maybe consider $e^{\ln 3 x}$ and just take integers. This amounts to asking why $\frac{1}{3^n}$ and $3^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{3}$ are different.

Graphically, as $x \to 0$, we see that $1/e^x$ just goes to $1$, whereas $e^{(1/x)}$ gets very large, heuristically since for rational numbers $e^{\frac{1}{1/n}}=e^n$

Comment: Actually, $e^{1/x}$ gets large as $x\to 0^+$. As $x\to 0^-$, it gets small (hence the limit does not exist as $x\to 0$).

Comment: That is exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1):

I think of them both as $e^x$ with different things done to the domain.

With $e^{-x}$, the domain is flipped around backwards, so the usual end behaviors for plus and minus infinity are swapped. With $e^{1/x}$, the domain is turned inside out, with the end behaviors being brought in around $x=0$ and stuffed into finite intervals, and the usual behavior around $x=0$ being flung out to infinity in both directions.

The other differences between these functions are largely consequences of this. The transformation $x\mapsto -x$ is a fairly simple one, equivalent to just looking at the graph in a mirror. Thus, continuity, end behavior, derivative and antiderivative aren't changed very dramatically.

On the other hand, the transformation $x\mapsto \frac1x$ is a much more... violent action on the real line. Infinite intervals are stuffed into finite intervals, and a singularity is induced around the origin. This has much more drastic effects on the graph, its continuity, and its derivative and antiderivative.